# NHibernate - QBE and EnableLike()

Tags: nhibernate

I have a problem using QBE with NHibernate.

Here's a sample code:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.FirstName = "e";
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.CreateSession())
{
  Example example =    Example.Create(person).ExcludeProperty("DateOfBirth").EnableLike().IgnoreCase();
  IList<Person> people = session.CreateCriteria<Person>().Add(example).List<Person>();
  return people;
}
```

What I expect is that this example & criteria will return all persons whose first name starts with an "e". BUT, to accomplish this I had to insert escape character in the example object's property. Like this:

```
person.FirstName = "e%";
```

With this modification, query returns the desired results. 
Shouldn't the "EnableLike" take care of this?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not an expert, but seems you need to put a matchmode in your enablelike(), just like:

Example.Create(person).ExcludeProperty("DateOfBirth")
.EnableLike(NHibernate.Expression.MatchMode.Start)
.IgnoreCase();

the matchmode can be:start, end,exact and anywhere

hope this help